# Inventory system adds new object instead of increasing amount by 1

Tags: python, inventory

I am trying to make an inventory system where obtaining an item you already have just increases the item's amount rather than adding a whole new one to the list.

```
def enc1():
  print("hello")

def enc2():
  print("hi")

def enc3():
  print("howdy")

def enc4():
  print("hey")

def enc5():
  print("heyo")

class item:
  def __init__(self, name, amount):
    self.name = name
    self.amount = amount

items = []

apple = item("apple", 1)

def addItem(itemToAdd):
  for x in items:
    if(x == itemToAdd):
      itemToAdd.self.amount += 1
    else:
      items.append(itemToAdd)

addItem(apple)
print(items, apple.amount)
addItem(apple)
print(items, apple.amount)

encounter = random.randint(1,5)

if(encounter == 1):
  enc1()
elif(encounter == 2):
  enc2()
elif(encounter == 3):
  enc3()
elif(encounter == 4):
  enc4()
elif(encounter == 5):
  enc5()
```

Comment: Hint: How would two items know they are the same?

Comment: Next hint: [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__eq__#object.__eq__)

Comment: You could use a dictionary instead, btw. `from collections import Counter`